# BFS in Javascript to find first anchor that satisfies href = N

Tags: javascript, dom, search, breadth-first-search

Given a DOM element.

How can I make a **BFS** so that, for all its children ( and children of children and so on...) I can find at which level it is found an `<a>` element that satisfies the **href** attribute is equal to X. Being X an array of possible values.

Here is what I have so far, but I am failing to see how/when increase a depth variable:

```
function findAnchorBFS(element) {
    if (element.nodeName == 'A' && isHrefHost(element.href)) {
        return 0; // this is the main level
    }

    var elements = [element];
    var level = 0;

    while (elements.length) {
        var newElements = [];
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var children = elements[i].children;
            for (var j=0; j < children.length; j++) {
                var child = children[j];
                if (child.nodeName == 'A' && isHrefHost(child.href)) {
                    return true;
                }
                newElements.push(child);
            }
        }
        elements = newElements;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: Barmar, but how would I find the depth of it once I found it?

Comment: When you enqueue each element, enqueue it as an object containing both the element and its depth. Then when you dequeue an element, you know its original depth. When you enqueue its children, they get `depth+1`.

Comment: Barmar, I am going to try to do it similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164500/javascript-getelementid-from-scratch-using-bfs without recursion.

Comment: Barmar, I have added my BFS approach. I first check the passed element to see if its that one, if not, I loop over children. However, I fail to see when/how I would use a depth variable. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code modified to record depth:

```
function findAnchorBFS(element) {
    if (element.nodeName == 'A' && isHrefHost(element.href)) {
        return 0; // this is the main level
    }

    var elements = [{ el: element, depth: 0 }];

    while (elements.length) {
        var newElements = [];
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var newDepth = elements[i].depth + 1;
            var children = elements[i].el.children;
            for (var j=0; j < children.length; j++) {
                var child = children[j];
                if (child.nodeName == 'A' && isHrefHost(child.href)) {
                    return newDepth;
                }
                newElements.push({ el: child, depth: newDepth });
            }
        }
        elements = newElements;
    }

}
```

Comment: Barmar, is it "correct" to do that first if for the passed element? Or, you think recursion would be better? Because I feel I am doing that checking twice (one for the "first" element) and then for the children

Comment: I think it's right. I just fixed the initial value of `elements` to use `depth: 0` -- I forgot that I increment it after reading it.